# White ring around inside of hard boiled egg yolk?

Tags: food-safety, eggs, hard-boiled-eggs

I hard boiled this egg the other day and when I sliced it open today to eat it I noticed there’s a white ring around the inside of the yolk. What is this? Is it still safe to eat?

[image: Half of a hard boiled egg sitting on a napkin yolk-side up. The yolk is a bit pale and there is a white ring around the center of it.]